# How to get hibernate to store a date?

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, hibernate

I have a Spring / Hibernate project and I am trying to store a date into the database but it's not working. It must be something stupid but I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
user.setFailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount(0);
user.setLastLoginDate(new Date());
user.setIsOnline(true);
```

The other two variables (failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount and isOnline) are getting written to the database without issue. I have also tried it with just passing a java.util.Date instead of a java.sql.Timestamp...same result. Here is how the property is defined on the user object:

```
private Date lastLoginDate;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="last_login_date")
public Date getLastLoginDate() {
    return this.lastLoginDate;
}

public void setLastLoginDate(Date lastLoginDate) {
    this.lastLoginDate = lastLoginDate;
}
```

Here is the column definition:

```
`last_login_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL
```

Any help? I don't even know what else to look for as this should be working.

Some more detail about the error: No errors or strange messages in the hibernate log. The hibernate log is showing a parameterized query but it isn't telling me what it is actually writing. It looks like it's not updating the column at all. In other words, if there is already a date there it doesn't change, or if it is null it doesn't change.

Update: I have looked at the logs and it looks like hibernate does write the proper data, but then immediately writes the incorrect data again. I see the following entry in the log:

```
11:15:12.280 [http-bio-8080-exec-26] TRACE o.h.e.def.AbstractSaveEventListener - detached instance of: com.hi.model.User
11:15:12.280 [http-bio-8080-exec-26] TRACE o.h.e.def.DefaultMergeEventListener - merging detached instance
```

And right after that I see it putting the old value back in for the lastLoginDate.

Comment: What is the failure? Is it just writing a `NULL`? Is it producing an error message? Is it writing something strange to the log?

Comment: @DonalFellows I've added some more details to the end of my post.

Comment: Mapping issue? Have you tried to put the annotation @column to the field instead of the function?

Comment: @JulienMay I tried that, it didn't make a difference.

Comment: where are you saving this user?

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman, it's being saved to a MySQL database.

Comment: I do almost exactly this in my application.  I think the length definition in your @Column annotation looks suspicious.  Try removing it, and just use user.setLastLoginDate(new Date()); - works for me. Also, if you put on TRACE logging for org.hibernate, it will show you what parameter values it's using for the insert.

Comment: I also think like John Ferrelly. Its not that much complex thing. I also work like that, what he mentioned. Your Date and TimeStamp is compatible. what you want will be exactly if you remove the length and put `new Date()` into the setter and make the type of `lastLoginDate`, util.Date.

Comment: I've taken out the timestamp as well as the length on the column definition. It didn't help.

Comment: OK I found more information in the hibernate log. Please see the end of my post.

Comment: I found the problem. Thanks for all your help, even though we went down a rabbit hole I learned a lot and wouldn't have found it otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I am refactoring some code and it looks like I was doing this:

```
//get user object
User user = getUser();
//call a function which modifies user
functionModifiesUser();
//modify user
user.blah = blah;
entityManager.merge(user);
```

So the parent function had a stale copy of the user object when I tried to save it. Actually, removing the merge statement was enough to fix it. But I have refactored the code to put all this in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using

```
Date date = new Date();
user.setLastLoginDate(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
```

and not just this?

```
user.setLastLoginDate(new Date());
```

First - You may not want to use Date and Timestamp at the same time.(e.g. for collections, etc)

> There are some classes in the Java platform libraries that do extend an instantiable
>   class and add a value component. For example, java.sql.Timestamp
>   extends java.util.Date and adds a nanoseconds field. The equals implementation
>   for Timestamp does violate symmetry and can cause erratic behavior if
>   Timestamp and Date objects are used in the same collection or are otherwise intermixed.
>   The Timestamp class has a disclaimer cautioning programmers against
>   mixing dates and timestamps. While you won’t get into trouble as long as you
>   keep them separate, there’s nothing to prevent you from mixing them, and the
>   resulting errors can be hard to debug. This behavior of the Timestamp class was a
>   mistake and should not be emulated. (Bloch, Effective Java, 2nd Ed.)

Second - I checked your examples, and it works fine for me on mysql-connector(5.1.21) / hibernate (4.0.1)

I prepared simple test project with arquillian integration test(You need to prepare jboss before running it):
https://github.com/rchukh/StackOverflowTests/tree/master/13803848

If you can provide some more information it might help - hibernate version, mysql version, mysql engine(MyISAM, InnoDB, etc.)
Otherwise it is possible that this is just a misconfiguration.

Comment: I was doing it the 2nd way at first. I changed it to the 1st way (using java.sql.Timestamp) to see if there was an issue just passing the date. I'll get back to you with the configuration details...

Answer (score -1):

Setting the column `last_login_date` as `timestamp` should work, at least works for me.

Comment: Well, yes I know it should work. The question is why isn't it working? I'm not quite sure how you think this is an answer to my question.

Comment: So why are you making a `Timestamp` instead of a `Date`, when your column is of type `datetime`?

Comment: java.sql.Timestamp is just more specific than Date. It is a subclass of Date. I tried it the other way, it didn't make a difference.